# Accessing a class static variable outside of module

Tags: python

I have a class:

```
class WidgetCheckbox(Widget,ObjectValue,ObjectEvents,ObjectModifiers):
    dialogarguments = (True,False,False)
    def __init__(self,hitdata, name,value):
        Widget.__init__(self,hitdata, name)
        ObjectValue.__init__(self,value,True,False,False)
        ObjectEvents.__init__(self,"change")
        ObjectModifiers.__init__(self)
```

And I have a class in another module that tries to get the value of dialog arguments:

```
def createWidget(self,blank,title,dialog_panel,insert_function,widget_class):
    dialog = AddDialog(self,title,dialog_panel,self.hitdata,*widget_class.dialogarguments)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_ADD:
        self.addReplace(blank,insert_function,widget_class,*dialog.getAdd())
    dialog.Destroy()
```

The problem I am having is that when it runs I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'WidgetCheckbox' has no attribute 'dialogarguments'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

The traceback I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jack/PycharmProjects/HIT/gui/widgets.py", line 82, in onBlankClick
    self.createWidget(blank,*self.tools[tool])
  File "/Users/jack/PycharmProjects/HIT/gui/widgets.py", line 86, in createWidget
    dialog = AddDialog(self,title,dialog_panel,self.hitdata,*widget_class.dialogarguments)
AttributeError: type object 'WidgetCheckbox' has no attribute 'dialogarguments'
```

where `self.tools` is

```
self.tools = {
            data.tools.BUTTON: ("Add Button",PropertiesTextPanel,self.table.insertButton,WidgetButton)
            ,data.tools.CHECKBOX: ("Add Checkbox",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertCheckbox,WidgetCheckbox)
            ,data.tools.LABEL: ("Add Label",PropertiesTextPanel,self.table.insertLabel,WidgetLabel)
            ,data.tools.COMBOBOX: ("Add Combobox",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertCombobox,WidgetCombobox)
            ,data.tools.TABLE: ("Add Table",PropertiesGridPanel,self.table.insertTable,WidgetTable)
            ,data.tools.GRAPH: ("Add Graph",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertGraph,WidgetGraph)
            ,data.tools.MODELABEL: ("Add Mode Label",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertModeLabel,WidgetModeLabel)
            ,data.tools.NUMBERLABEL: ("Add Number Label",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertNumberLabel,WidgetNumberLabel)
            ,data.tools.NUMBER: ("Add Number",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertNumber,WidgetNumber)
            ,data.tools.RADIO: ("Add Radio",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertRadio,WidgetRadio)
            ,data.tools.TOGGLE: ("Add Toggle",PropertiesValuePanel,self.table.insertToggle,WidgetToggle)
        }
```

Comment: How are you calling `createWidget`? Could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added it in edit.

Comment: Your traceback doesn't correspond to your code anymore (`dialogarguments` vs. `getDialogArguments`; please update your code as well, if you altered it. Also, that makes it harder to help you, if you alter the code in the meantime. (The edit suggests it's now a static/class method, not a class attribute.)

Comment: Updated the traceback, sorry

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't really matter for the error, but it reads better.

Comment: Further: have you tried littering your code with `print(dir(WidgetCheckbox))` statements between start and crash point? Or use a debugger? Just to find out whether `dialogarguments` was ever there on the class.

Comment: Did what you suggested, this is every much my fault same class name different module

Comment: Ah, you gotta love simple old-fashioned debugging; get rids of (silly) errors 90% of the time ;-).